# How to get overlayview in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uisearchbar

I need a help . Actually when I tap or click on search button then I should get a black screen . As you could see using in `ABPeoplePicker`.So it is possible with `UITableView` ? I've added an image that can help you in getting my question.

here is my code :-

```
  -(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
      if(searching)
          return;
      [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
      searching = YES;
      letUserSelectRow = NO;
      [contactTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
  }
```

![Example image][1]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `UISearchDisplayController` instead of a `UISearchBar`, the black screen will come automatically. If you need it in some other places than `UISearchBar`, you have to add view with black background color and show/hide it when needed.

Comment: Sorry . I've tried using UISearchDisplayController instead of a UISearchBar but i can't get my result.

Comment: It should work even without UITableView, just drag and drop another UISearchDisplayController and focus the UISearchBar.

Comment: thanx for replying .But can't it be done programmatically ? Still wondering how to do though i'm very new to iphone dev .

Comment: Oh! I just dragged new UISearchDisplayController to my UIViewController and works fine without any change or settings. Not sure what is the problem in your case, some experts here will help you then. :-)

Comment: u can add a uiview with alpha value as .5 and it will look the same as u want it